# How to save a Many-To-Many relationship with custom properties with typeORM Query Builder?

Tags: typeorm, query-builder

I need to create a many-to-many relationship between the tables `organisation` and `user`, where each `user` can have a `role` (admin, follower...) in the `organisation`.

I have :

Organization

```
@Entity('organization')
class Organization extends BaseColumns {
    @Column({ type: 'character varying', unique: true })
        name: string;

    @OneToMany(() => OrganizationUser, (organizationUser) => organizationUser.organization, { cascade: true })
        organizationUser: OrganizationUser[];
}
```

User

```
@Entity('user')
class User extends BaseColumns {
    @Column({ type: 'character varying', unique: true })
        email: string;

    @Column({ type: 'character varying', name: 'password-hash' })
        passwordHash: string | null;

    @OneToMany(() => OrganizationUser, (organizationUser) => organizationUser.user, { cascade: true })
        organizationUser: OrganizationUser[];
}
```

Role

```
@Entity('role')
class Role extends BaseColumns {
    @Column({ type: 'enum', enum: RoleType, default: RoleType.Contributor })
        name: RoleType;

    @OneToMany(() => OrganizationUser, (organizationUser: OrganizationUser) => organizationUser.role, { cascade: true })
        organizationUser: OrganizationUser[];
}
```

OrganizationUser

```
@Entity('organization-user')
class OrganizationUser extends BaseColumns {
    @Column({ name: 'user-id' })
        userId: string;

    @Column({ name: 'organization-id' })
        organizationId: string;

    @ManyToOne(() => Role, (role: Role) => role.organizationUser, { cascade: true })
        role: Role;

    @ManyToOne(() => User, (user: User) => user.organizationUser)
        user: User;

    @ManyToOne(() => Organization, (organization: Organization) => organization.organizationUser)
        organization: Organization;
}
```

How can I add a new insertion in the database with the typeORM Query Builder please ?